# In Haskell, is there infinity :: Num a => a?

Tags: haskell, infinity

I'm trying to implement a data structure where if I had the use of infinity for numerical comparison purposes, it would simply things greatly. Note this isn't maxBound/minBound, because a value can be <= maxbound, but all values would be < infinity.

No hope?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe you want a Maybe type?

```
data Infinite a = Infinite | Only a
```

then write a Num instance for Num a => Infinite a, with the numeric rules you need.

Comment: Getting obvious there is no solution, so I've basically adopt your approach: `data Num a => Inf a = NegInf | Val a | PosInf`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nooo, please don't put a type class constraint on a data declaration! :-)

Answer (score 30):

Well how about that! It turns out if you just type `1/0` it returns `Infinity`! On ghci:

```
Prelude> 1/0
Infinity
Prelude> :t 1/0
1/0 :: (Fractional t) => t
Prelude> let inf=1/0
Prelude> filter (>=inf) [1..]
```

and then of course it runs forever, never finding a number bigger than infinity. (But see ephemient's comments below on the actual behavior of `[1..]`)

Comment: IMO, `encodeFloat (floatRadix 0 - 1) (snd $ floatRange 0)` is a better way to get `Infinity` (with type `(RealFrac a) => a`).  That being said, because of floating-point imprecision `[1..]` is never going to get past a finite upper bound, so what you have here is a poor demonstration.

Comment: Darn. I knew I shouldn't have claimed a program would run forever after watching it run for a finite amount of time.

Comment: You misunderstand.  At some point, the tail will just be `[x, x, x, x, x, ..]`, because floating `x+1 == x` when `x` is large enough, even though there exist higher, finite `y` (for example, `encodeFloat (floatRadix 0 - 1) (snd (floatRange 0) - 1)`).  Obviously `x < y < inf`; my point was that this isn't a good demonstration of infinity.

Comment: This can also be written as `recip 0`

Comment: @ephemient I believe that is incorrect, though I can't say if it was true when you made that comment. The current implementations of `Enum` for floating point types take that issue into account and will happily sail right past the number you are talking about (the `x` where `x + 1 == x`).

Answer (score 29):

```
infinity = read "Infinity"
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer if the code is floating-point. People tend to forget about floating-point infinity.

Answer (score 10):

Try something like this. However, to get `Num` operations (like `+` or `-`) you will need to define `Num` instance for `Infinitable a` type. Just like I've done it for `Ord` class.

```
data Infinitable a = Regular a | NegativeInfinity | PositiveInfinity deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Ord a => Ord (Infinitable a) where
    compare NegativeInfinity NegativeInfinity = EQ
    compare PositiveInfinity PositiveInfinity = EQ
    compare NegativeInfinity _ = LT
    compare PositiveInfinity _ = GT
    compare _ PositiveInfinity = LT
    compare _ NegativeInfinity = GT
    compare (Regular x) (Regular y) = compare x y    

main =
    let five = Regular 5
        pinf = PositiveInfinity::Infinitable Integer
        ninf = NegativeInfinity::Infinitable Integer
        results = [(pinf > five), (ninf < pinf), (five > ninf)]
    in
        do putStrLn (show results)
```

Comment: By the way: if you define your `Infinitable` data type with the `NegativeInfinity` case first, then the `Regular` and the `PositiveInfinity` last, you can derive `Ord` for free. (If you did it this way to give a relatively simple example, please disregard this comment!)

Answer (score 6):

```
λ: let infinity = (read "Infinity")::Double
λ: infinity > 1e100
True
λ: -infinity < -1e100
True
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at my [RangedSets library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Ranged-sets), which does exactly this in a very general way.  I defined a "Boundary" type so that a value of type "Boundary a" is always either above or below any given "a".  Boundaries can be "AboveAll", "BelowAll", "Above x" and "Below x".

Answer (score 2):

You can work with the [**`ieee754`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ieee754) which offers an [**`IEEE`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ieee754-0.7.1/docs/Numeric-IEEE.html#t:IEEE). This typeclass has an `infinity` member. The typeclass is implemented for `Float`, `Double`, `CFloat` and `CDouble`.

You thus install the `ieee-754` package, and then obtain positive infinity (or negative infinity) with:

```
ghci> import Numeric.IEEE
ghci> infinity :: Double
Infinity
ghci> -infinity :: Double
-Infinity
```

For `Float`s, `Double`s, etc. it is [implemented as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ieee754-0.7.1/docs/src/Numeric-IEEE.html#line-142):

> ```
>     infinity = 1/0
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If your use case is that you have boundary conditions that sometimes need to be checked, but sometimes not, you can solve it like this:

```
type Bound a = Maybe a

withinBounds :: (Num a, Ord a) => Bound a -> Bound a -> a -> Bool
withinBounds lo hi v = maybe True (<=v) lo && maybe True (v<=) hi
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a more principled approach based on an idea from non-standard analysis. Given a totally ordered ring R of characteristic zero, you can consider the Laurent ring R[inf,1/inf] with the natural lexicographic total ordering. For example, you have:

```
for all x>0 in R,
.. -inf < -x < -d < -d^2 < .. < 0 < .. < d^2 < d < x < inf < inf^2 < .. 
where d = 1/inf.
```

This way the Laurent ring R[inf,1/inf] is again a totally ordered Z-algebra, i.e. an instance of `Num`, with other niceties you possibly want, including +/-infinity, +/-infinitesimal, second-order infinitesimals, etc.. But note that it's not Archimedian and induction will no longer work, which is a sort of second-order arithmetic. For implementation take a look at [this example](https://github.com/nishiuramakoto/vismem/blob/master/Hyper.hs). As in the comment in the code this construction should work for other algebras, such as the list monad. You can think of lists where two elements are "infinitely close"  "second-order infinitely far away" etc. (which leads to a generalization of rose trees.)