# Can I constrain the parametric polymorphic type on type/data constructor in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, api-design, parametric-polymorphism

I have a parameterised type that I'd like to constrain to a numeric type, more specifically a `Fractional`, e.g.:

```
data Rating a = (Fractional a) => Score a | Unscored deriving (Show, Eq)
```

so that the user of the API can define which non-integer type they might utilise (`Float` or `Double`?), but the internal API code I write can still perform arithmetic operations on a numeric type. I do not want it to be an integer because results of my "internal operations" may not be integers and my understanding is that using `Fractional` would lead to more accurate results.

Compiling the above (in GHCI at least) gives me the following error:

```
    Data constructor `Score' has existential type variables, a context, or a specialised result type
  Score :: forall a. Fractional a => a -> Rating a
  (Use ExistentialQuantification or GADTs to allow this)
In the definition of data constructor `Score'
In the data declaration for `Rating'
```

which suggests to me I'm doing something that I probably don't want to keep trying; i.e. my design is rubbish.

I guess I'm trying to say the following in this API: "when you use a Rating type, its parameter must be a subclass of `Fractional` so I can perform accurate arithmetic on it". How might I achieve this? Or am I way off the mark and/or overengineering?

Comment: Already discussed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770278/typeclass-constraints-on-data-declarations).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks. I still like the API-design aspects of my question though, and Twan's answer below satisfies agrees with my other solution which was to contrain it on the functions, which is not covered in that other question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't put the `Fractional` constraint on the datatype, but rather on the functions that work with it. So

```
data Rating a = Score a | Unscored deriving (Show, Eq)

makeSomeRating :: Fractional a => a -> Rating a
makeSomeRating x = Score (x / 2) -- can use Fractional functions here

doSomethingElseWithRating :: Fractional a => Rating a -> Something
```

Comment: I had wondered this. My reason for not doing so was that I had attached the need to work with `Fractional`s to the `Rating` type, i.e. it doesn't make sense to use a `Rating` if you're not working with some derivative of `Fractional` (but which one is used is up to the user...). Does this make sense? Not sure if it changes your answer or not...

Comment: @atc, this answer reflects community consensus about best practices. People have tried a lot of things, and this is the way that usually works best. There are special circumstances where a GADT is the way to go, but this isn't one of those. Also, note that this answer writer's standing in the Haskell community far exceeds his SO reputation score ;-)

Comment: I was just trying to add a little more context and certainly wasn't intending to argue or suggest Twan was wrong, just trying to express my thoughts were around why I was attempting what I was.

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you can do this with `GADTs`:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, StandaloneDeriving #-}

data Rating a where
    Score :: (Fractional a) => a -> Rating a
    Unscored :: Rating a

deriving instance (Show a) => Show (Rating a)
deriving instance (Eq a) => Eq (Rating a)

-- No need for a context here!
halfScore :: Rating a -> Rating a
halfScore (Score a) = Score (a / 2)
halfScore Unscored = Unscored
```

`StandaloneDeriving` is necessary because GHC can't derive `Show` and `Eq` for GADTs otherwise.