# What is `Cons` in Data.FixedList source code?

Tags: haskell

In the source code for [Data.FixedList](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-list-0.1.6/docs/src/Data-FixedList.html#FixedList28), I found the following definition:

```
data FixedList f =>
  Cons f a = (:.) {
    head :: a,
    tail :: (f a)
  }  deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

As someone very new to Haskell, it's hard to figure out what's going on here. I understand syntax such as `data TypeName = TypeName { a :: Int, b :: Int} deriving (Show)` or `data TypeName = TypeA | TypeB`, but the code above is over my head. Any documentation / or walk-through would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all the `FixedList f =>` enforces the constraint that `f` is a `FixedList` when using the constructor. I'm not sure why it's used here. It is generally [advised against](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770278/typeclass-constraints-on-data-declarations).

In Haskell, you can make infix data constructors with symbols starting with `:`. In the library, the constructor is put in brackets `(:.)` so it can be used with record syntax. Without record syntax it would look like this:

```
data Cons f a = a :. f a
```

Pattern matching is very similar to lists. Here's a simple function using it:

```
mapHead :: FixedList f => (a -> a) -> Cons f a -> Cons f a
mapHead f (a :. as) = f a :. as
```

Here's a definition without using an infix constructor.

```
data Cons f a = Cons
  { head :: a
  , tail :: f a
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is mostly fancy formatting of things you've seen before.

```
data FixedList f => Cons f a = (:.) { head :: a
                                    , tail :: (f a)
                                    } deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

`FixedList f` is just a typeclass constraint on the `Cons f a` datatype. `(:.)` is an infix data constructor.