# How can we make use of `Infinity` that Haskell returns when you do `2/0`

Tags: haskell

I understand that Haskell tries to do something more beneficial than simply throwing an error when one does division by zero

```
test :: Int -> Int -> String
test a b = case a/b of
    Infinity -> "fool"
    x  -> Show x
```

However i was told my ghc that `Infinity` is not a data constructor. What is it actually and how can i make use of it? I don't want to simply check `b` for 0

Comment: [isNaN](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:isNaN)

Comment: Just for context or if you want to read more about this, the behavior you're asking about isn't specific to haskell but is an aspect of the IEEE 754 floating point standard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a handful of ways to do this. My preferred one would be to use [`isInfinite`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:isInfinite) from the Prelude:

```
test :: Int -> Int -> String
test a b = case fromIntegral a / fromIntegral b of
             x | isInfinite x && x > 0 -> "fool"
               | otherwise -> show x
```

Alternately, you could define `infinity` as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354707/in-haskell-is-there-infinity-num-a-a) and compare for equality (since `Infinity == Infinity`).

---

Your code also had a couple of issues I assume are unrelated to your question:

- `Show` should be `show`
- `(/)` doesn't work for `Int` arguments, so you need to use `fromIntegral` to convert `a` and `b` to something floating

I also suspect you aware this particular function doesn't require an infinity check...

```
test :: Int -> Int -> String
test a 0 | a > 0 = "fool"
         | otherwise = show (fromIntegral a / fromIntegral b)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and pointing out the problems. Yeah i was just trying to illustrate my doubts quickly.

Comment: @laiboonh I figured. :)

Comment: Instead of using `fromIntegral` here, it would usually make more sense to adjust the argument types to be floating point. Coercing with `fromIntegral` yourself prevents the user from choosing a type, *and* forces GHC to use defaulting rules, which are a bit weird.

Comment: What *is* `Infinity`, though? Hard-coded representation of IEEE infinity?

Comment: @chepner in the case of `Float` at least, looks like `Infinity` is the representation of numbers that satisfy `isInfinite` and `> 0`